# Strategy for creating profile page for user with Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform

So I'm making an app that will have a user profile on one of the tabs. I have never made an app like this and am wondering about how I will go about it exactly. The profile page will have no images, just text. I am writing an iOS app in swift.

I was thinking this way: make the profile page a table cell in a `tableview`. Have the user enter the info into text fields, then save them as part of the Parse User class. In parse, there will be different columns under the User class: age, name, email, about me, etc. These will be displayed as labels on the user interface in the `tableView` cell.

so under func tableview.numbersOfRowsinSection, I will return 1. In the `PFQuery`, I will query for the User class for `createdAt` in `orderDescending`, so that the only profile that ever displays is the last updated one.

obviously this is far from a complete picture of everything needed, but is it at least a good starting point ?

also i searched quite a bit looking for info about how to create user profile pages with parse before asking this, does anyone have any good references or tutorials available on how to do it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Imagine your Profile page comes to you in the form of a JSON file.  And this JSON has every bit of detail you need in order to make your profile.  Figure out how to make your Profile using this JSON.  Once you feel like this is a good design.  Make a parse entity similar to the JSON.  Then as you need it, pull the data from parse and fill out your Profile page.

Comment: I'm actually relatively new to developing apps and programming, and have never worked with JSON before, so I don't think this strategy would be very good for me. thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: In that case use one big Dictionary